# Displacement node doesn't seem to work

Tags: mesh, node-editor, shaders, displacement

I've been trying to get the displacement node to work in blender 2.80, but am having no luck:

[image]

It doesn't seem to show up in the cycles render either:

[image]

anyone know what I have to do to get it to work?

Comment: I think it does not work in Eevee for now. Use Cycles instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to enable true displacement in Cycles, make sure the box highlighted in the imagine below (Materials Tab > Settings > Surface > "Displacement" Box) is set to "Displacement Only" or "Displacement and Bump". Use whichever works best for you. 
[image: a screenshot of Blender highlighting the displacement type option for a material]

Comment: alright, it worked, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to use simple "fake" displacement (basically bumpiness that is affected by lighting, but is not visible in silhouette), you've already got it working. If you are attempting to use "true" displacement from the displacement node in the material, this will not work in Evee. Use Cycles or the displacement modifier.

Also, even in Cycles, the results of true displacement from the material displacement node do not affect the mesh in edit mode view: it is computed at render time.

Comment: It didn't show up in the render ... used cycles

Comment: and yes, im trying to get "true" displacement. i know how to use the modifier but this way feels more elegant and would therefore like to use this.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently unavailable in Eevee, when using cycles be sure to enable it under material settings (as see in other answer).

If you would like true displacement in Eevee or to see the displacement in preview and editing (or you need collision vs the displacement), you may bake the displacement texture and use it in a regular displacement modifier. Be sure to enable floating point precision on your displacement texture.